# Nuxt 3 - Aliases - How can aliases be used inside a config file?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nuxt.config.js

When trying to importing files through aliases at the configuration (**nuxt.config.ts**), an error occurs: **Cannot find module '~/....**

There is an example: [codesnadbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tender-worker-l41rok?file=%2Fnuxt.config.ts%3A8%2C1)

### Short example

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
import { book } from "~/vars";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    bookApiEndpoint: book.apiEndpoint || "",
  },
});
```

### Full example

If use an absolute path, then file will be imported:

```
import { book } from "./vars";
```

But if there is another import through the alias inside the file, then there will be an error again (pic.1):

**./vars.ts**

```
export * from "~/entities";
```

**./entities/index.ts**

```
export * from "./book";
```

**./entities/book.ts**

```
export const book = {
    apiEndpoint: '/api/book'
}
```

There is an example: [codesnadbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tender-worker-l41rok?file=%2Fnuxt.config.ts%3A8%2C1)

### Question

How can aliases be used inside a config file?

Thank you in advance!

There is an example: [codesnadbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tender-worker-l41rok?file=%2Fnuxt.config.ts%3A8%2C1)

Answer (score 1):

Aliases for `@` and `~` mapping to the project root are already pre-configured in Nuxt but are only available during runtime compilation.

They are **not available** to use for compilation setup and configuration, IDE's will wrongly auto-complete imports with `~` alias instead of `.` dot notation.

You have to use the traditional directory dot notations in config files to import other files into them.

You will be fine to use `@` *(at)* and `~` *(tilde)* everywhere else in your project where files are part of the compilation process not compilation setup.

```js
import { book } from './vars'
```